# How to create notifications that don't go away when clicked in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

```
int icon = R.drawable.icon4;        
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello"; // ticker-text
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
Context context = getApplicationContext();     
CharSequence contentTitle = "Hello";  
CharSequence contentText = "Hello";      
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

This won't work for me.

How could I create a notification that is clickable and goes to my app, but does not go away when clicked?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder/35279147#35279147

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should read the whole things not just a part, buddy. Please re-read carefully step-by-step.

```
// this
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.icon4;        
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello"; // ticker-text
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
Context context = getApplicationContext();     
CharSequence contentTitle = "Hello";  
CharSequence contentText = "Hello";      
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

// and this
private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Comment: `setLatestEventInfo()` was deprecated in API level 11. Have to use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead.

Comment: I have use same code for notification.. Now if i want to add button in notification then how can achive...? Please help me

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically.

Answer (score 12):

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent  pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
Notification notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        notification = new Notification(icon, "Title", when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(
                context,
                "Title",
                "Text",
                pending);
    } else {
        notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText(
                        "Text").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pending).setWhen(when).setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
    }
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
nm.notify(0, notification);
```

Or you can Download direct tutorial from here : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/how-to-create-local-notification-notification-manager-demo-with-example-android-source-code_26

Comment: Is this correct? You create a `PendingIntent` but it's not used then. At least when < 11, it should be the last parameter to `setLatestEventInfo`, or am I wrong?

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android 5.0 > it became a lot easier, functionallity changed, but you can use the same code.

```
//Some Vars
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1; //this can be any int


//Building the Notification
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);
builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotifications Sample");
builder.setContentText("Time to learn about notifications!");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Make sure you are in an application context, if not you may need to pass the context and change your sourcecode as follows

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
...
..
.

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
            context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

**You can see the full-source-code at:**
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicNotifications/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicnotifications/MainActivity.java#L73

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Here if you want notifications that don't go away when clicked in Android?
so set

```
setAutoCancel(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>16)
    {
        notificationManager.notify(5, notification.build());
    }else
    {
        notificationManager.notify(5, notification.getNotification());
    }
```

To work in `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16` keep in mind to do some changes