# App crashes when alarms get received

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

MobMy BrodcastReceiver's OnReceive, it works great only when the app is running in the background, I get the notification no problem, but as soon as the user closes the app and waits for the date he specified to be reminded it crashes, is it because the app isn't running? So I'm guessing it's because my app isn't running so the intents can't be retrieved? That's the reason why it crashes?

How I set my alarms, pretty basic stuff;

```
   public void setAlarm(View view) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayDate);
    long alertTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    // store id
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", mainId);
    alertIntent.putExtra("name", name);
    alertIntent.putExtra("releaseDate", releaseDate);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, mainId, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, pendingIntent);

}
```

My BrodcastReceiver's OnReceive

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra("releaseDate");

    createNotification(context, "Movie Reminder", name + ": " + releaseDate, "Movie Reminder", id);
}
```

Maybe I could check if my app isn't running in the onReceive() and if not it opens the app?

Comment: Post the stacktrace/log please.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace and the `createNotification()` method.

Comment: Create notification isn't the problem here trust me

Comment: No stacktrace/log  is printed sorry \:(

Comment: We can't help you without a stacktrace and/or more code.

Comment: Sorry :( the app just crashes maybe because my app isn't running, it would be great if you could tell me how could I check if my app is running in the foreground or background

Comment: If it's running in the foreground, it's on-screen. Have you setup USB debugging on your device?

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues that might be wrong, without a Logcat, we cant be sure, but here are some of the most likely problems:

```
getStringExtra("something");
```

is returning [a null string, check documentation here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

context has no `createNotification` method, either create a static one and use your own, or [check here how to create a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526963/create-notification-app-in-android) or [here for a step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264805/how-to-create-notifications-in-android)