# Android, Urban AirShip - change the message

Tags: android, notifications, urbanairship.com

How to change the notification message in Android to localised it? 
I just want to change the message what I get from Urban AirShip before it will be display on notification bar?

Comment: do you want to modify the message coming from server ???

Comment: Yes, I just need to change the message before notification method will display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, its kind a dirty one, but right know I need to use this.
Just after get notification from Urban AirShip I cancel all  and send my own with changed message.

Answer (score 7):

You can using this method: `PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(null);` and send your own notification with android notification from the SDK

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to disable the default notification

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify the message once you  receive the message from Urban AirShip for your internal use in the app  **but can't show the modified message in the notification bar**.

You can check the message in your **IntentReceiver**

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String logTag = "Hey";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(logTag, "Received intent: " + intent.toString());
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED)) {

                int id = intent.getIntExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

          Log.v(logTag, "Received push notification. Alert: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT)
                + ". Payload: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA) + ". NotificationID="+id);

               //can get your message here

        } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {

            Log.v(logTag, "User clicked notification. Message: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT)+ ".Payload:" + intent.getStringExtra("PushManager.EXTRA_STRING_EXTRA"));


            Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

            UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);

        } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
            Log.i(logTag, "Registration complete. APID:" + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
                    + ". Valid: " + intent.getBooleanExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));


        }

            }
}
```

Comment: ok, so if I want to handle notification in other way? Just react on it by my way, dont use the default system from Urban AirShip?

Comment: see you can create your own custom layout with icon images to show on the notifcation bar , please download  sdk  sample code from Urban airship resource , you can see there a file named notification.xml that can be used as showing in notification bar....any other thing do you want...???

Comment: I need to localised the message, so before it appear on notification bar I need to change it. Urban AirShip I want to use only to trigger the event.

Comment: as I told you already that you can't show the modified message on notification it will be handled automatically.

Comment: so how to get the notification, but not show it on notification?

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers and came up with a combined solution.

1. You want to disable UrbanAirship's default notification handler. If you do that, it won't generate and show you the notifications at all.
   `PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(null);` (Using David T's suggestion)
2. You want to build your own notification. This can be done inside your `IntentReceiver`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder) link will do the trick.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Please using that code to disable Urban Airship's notifications, override BasicPushNotificationBuilder:

```
BasicPushNotificationBuilder nb = new BasicPushNotificationBuilder() {
    @Override
    public Notification buildNotification(String alert,
            Map<String, String> extras) {
        return null;
    }
};
// Disable notifications
PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
```