# Notification Build Check in Android

Tags: android, api, notifications

I am working on an app for Android, for which I'd like to use notifications. Now, it has come to my attention that Notification and setLatestEventInfo are both deprecated and will no longer be supported from API level 16 onwards (is that correct?).

I'd like my app to be supported from API level 11 (Android 3.0) up. Do I then just implement the new method NotificationCompat.Builder? Will this work in API's before level 16? Or do I have to use an if statement, checking the API level of the user's device, and then using Notification and setLatestEventInfo for anything between API levels 11 and 16, and NotificationCompat.Builder from API level 16 on up?

**EDIT:**

One more thing. I am using the code from developer.android.com for NotificationCompat.Builder and it gives the following error at TaskStackBuilder:

Class requires API level 16 (current min is 11): android.app.TaskStackBuilder

This is not solved if I use an if statement to check the API level.

Comment: try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392101/1056359

Comment: Yes I had found this answer too, but I got confused because he says: **Notification.Builder is in API 11, so if you are developing for anything earlier than 3.0 you should continue to use the old API.** And: **the NotificationCompat.Builder class has been added to the Support Package so we can use this to support API level v4 and up.** Does this mean that I can use Notification.Builder, but not NotificationCompat.Builder? Or does it mean that I should use Notification.Builder for API's between 11 and 16, and NotificationCompat.Builder for 16 and up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want it to work with the `Notification.Builder` in earlier APIs, you should use the support library that is included in the SDK.

when writing code for versions that came before API 11 you should include the support library and instead of calling the `Notification.Builder` you need to call `NotificationCompact` instead.

try reading in the [Android support Library page](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and going over the sample projects for these things.