# Persistent android notification from service

Tags: android, service, notifications, persistent

How can I make a persistent notification, that will update every time the users sees it?
form the service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show the notification when the `Service` is running, you call:

```
    startForeground(R.string.notification_id, myNotification);
```

giving the method an ID for your service, and a `Notification` that you have created.

---

At any point, your `Service` can update what the user sees by using the same `R.string.notification_id` and posting a new `Notification`:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_id, myNotification);
```

---

For creating a `Notification`, you need to read up on `Notification.Builder` ([android docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)).

There is also a good answer on a related question: [How exactly to use Notification.Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869647/383414) Apologies for not reposting his answer, but it includes a lot of code and will sort you out.

Comment: Say, time...when a user opens the notification slide thingy, he sees the current time. Is it possible?