# Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14): android.app.Notification.Builder#build

Tags: android, android-lint

[image]The documentation says Notification.Builder is Added in API level 11.
Why I get this lint error?

> Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14): android.app.Notification.Builder#build

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Am I missing something?

Correct me if I am wrong but the API is added in level 11, right?
[Added in API level 11](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks. Its a lint warning that notification builder requires api 16

Comment: scroll down the same page and check the topic below public methods

Comment: Thanks. the build method is added in level 16...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[NotificationBuilder.build()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#build()) requires API Level 16 or higher. Anything between API Level 11 & 15 you should use [NotificationBuilder.getNotification()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#getNotification%28%29). So use

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).getNotification();
```

Comment: courtesy comment Cammille in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8869647/931982

Comment: You mean the document is wrong? it says the api is added in Level 11.

Comment: not not wrong .. check the links i provided in answer.. there clearly writtern that build is from api 16.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev scroll down the same page (the link you posted in the question) and check the topic below public methods.

Comment: Alright, got it. My mistake...I saw the example on the top so I assume the build is added in Level 11. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 17):

The tip about the API level needing to be 16 is right. This worked for me

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    nm.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.getNotification());
} else {
    nm.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I was having the problem where the notification worked fine on newer devices but not on Android 4.0.4 (API level 15). I do get a deprecation warning form eclipse. 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") doesn't entirely hide it but I think that is probably helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Android Lint is a new tool introduced in ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs. It is available both as a command line tool, as well as integrated with Eclipse

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

For list of lint checks

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

For supressing lint warning

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

**If your app supports versions of Android as old as API level 4, you can instead use NotificationCompat.Builder, available in the Android Support library.**

For support library

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use from this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                        .setContentText("Subject")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).getNotification();
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, n);
            } else {
                Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                        .setContentText("Subject")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, n);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in android studio. I did minor change in **build.gradle(module:app)** file and Problem has been solved.
[image]

After sync project.