# How can I resize an image in android to use it in an expanded notification?

Tags: android, image, notifications, resize

That's how I define a style for the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new
                NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
notiStyle.setBigContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_ticker));
notiStyle.setSummaryText(title);
notiStyle.bigPicture(map);
notiStyle.bigLargeIcon(map); //map - bitmap
```

But the bitmap is too large, and notification shows only a piece of an image with full width and cropped   by height, a large icon shows a little part in the center of the image.

Comment: refer this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997093/android-notification-large-image-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code , it helps you :

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your Bitmap before setting it to the View with the following code.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));
```

Comment: Supriya, but from where should i know a needed size for different types of screens?

Comment: You should predefine sizes based on the device screensizes type(i.e., hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi)