# Notification on every 5 minutes

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to give the notification to user on every 5 minutes I am using following code.
it shows me notification first time but not give next time.

```
public void startAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long whenFirst = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyUser.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, whenFirst, 60*5000, pendingIntent);            
}

public class NotifyUser extends Service {   
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loadNotification(); 
    }

    private void loadNotification() {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher/*android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more*/, "Hanumanji waiting for you", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Context context = NotifyUser.this;
        CharSequence title = "Hanumanji is waiting for you";
        CharSequence details = "Do Hanuman Chalisa Parayan with ShlokApp.";
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyUser.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, pending);
        notify.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://pro.shlokapp.hanumanchalisa/"+ R.raw.game_sound_pause);
        nm.notify(0, notify);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {}

    public void onPause() {}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {}

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {}
}
```

Comment: are you sure 1/ you don't cancel the notification in the activity class ? 2/ you are not simply updating the existing notification ?

Comment: how to update existing notification?

Comment: When you call `nm.notify(0, notify);` you are always passing the same notification id (that is `0`), thus updating the existing notification instead of creating a new one. Pass different numbers for different notifications.

Comment: try return START_STICKY, and create a seperate class for the alarm service, and from that service call another service that creates or generates the notification. and AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP instead of AlarmManager.RTC

Answer (score 5):

**it shows me notification first time but not give next time.** : The reason is you use `nm.notify(0, notify);`
Do not use 0 as it will show latest notification.

Below code works like a charm :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    myTimer.schedule(myTask, 5000, 1500);

}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {

        generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "Hello");
    }
}

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
    // "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
                contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                .setContentText(message).build();

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

    }

}
```

}

Use Timer class. Change the timer interval as per your needs.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

in this post [How exactly to use Notification.Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder) there is an example. I used it to make the notification in my app. It also use the NotificationBuilder from the support library.

I think in your code above, you are just updating the notification, that is already there. Try to check it by displaying a number that is increased by one every time you set/update a new notification.

Hope this will help you =).

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity.java**  // It contains on a textview **tvTime**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SampleAlarmReceiver alarm;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> times;
    private ArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            displayTime();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        alarm = new SampleAlarmReceiver();
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
        times = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        times.add(time);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, times);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("display_time"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // When the user clicks START ALARM, set the alarm.
            case R.id.start_action:
                alarm.setAlarm(this);
                return true;
            // When the user clicks CANCEL ALARM, cancel the alarm. 
            case R.id.cancel_action:
                alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void displayTime() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        times.add(time);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**SampleAlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent("display_time");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent1);

    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(set_alarm)

    /**
     * Sets a repeating alarm that runs once a day at approximately 8:30 a.m. When the
     * alarm fires, the app broadcasts an Intent to this WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
     *
     * @param context given context
     */
    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                5 * 60 * 1000,  // After five minute
                5 * 60 * 1000,  // Every five minute
                alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels the alarm.
     *
     * @param context given context
     */
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr != null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the 
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

**SampleBootReceiver.java**

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SampleAlarmReceiver alarm;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm  = new SampleAlarmReceiver();
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml** // its a menu used in MainActivity

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/start_action"
        android:title="Start Alarm"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cancel_action"
        android:title="Stop Alarm"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmmanager">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SampleAlarmReceiver" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```