# How to display Notification on Android api level 19

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Resources res = this.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setTicker("helllo")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Messge").setContentText("Messge22");
        Notification n = builder.build();

        nm.notify(5, n);
    }
```

I am trying to use this Code for Send Notification On Button click but there is Error coming in Code it show Error  Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Notification.Builder#setContentIntent i have set Project Api Level 19 please help me where am doing wrong please suggest me Solution  target=android-19 Project Properties while I have to code for:

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: set android:minSdkVersion="11" in the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app supports versions of `Android` as old as API level 4, you can instead use `NotificationCompat.Builder`, available in the [Android Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

**Notification.Builder** - This class was added in `Android 3.0 Honeycomb [API 11]`.  So if you need to support older SDK’s you will need to use `NotificationCompact` instead.

**NotificationCompat.Builder** – This class is in the version `4 Support Library` (compatible Android 1.6 and up).

For more info go to [How exactly to use Notification.Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391870/how-exactly-to-use-notification-builder)

Comment: OK Suppoe if we ll set min sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" it will work for all device na ?

Comment: used `NotificationCompact`  for older Android versions support

Comment: where i will Use please Edit my code coz android:minSdkVersion="11" working fine but i want it in All so please Edit My code

Comment: No i am not..just go to [http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/) and do it by your self....

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  i want for this please help me

Comment: http://pastie.org/9636624 check this i have Use this code but unable to get Notification please check issue